# How to use float type properly in mysql?

Tags: mysql, floating-point, range

I have a table in mysql with a field type float(10, 7).
I am trying to insert value 1196.104, Even when using phpmyadmin it converts that value to 1000.0000000. 
What type should I use to properly store the value 1196.104 in database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is working exactly as intended by the `FLOAT(10,7)`. When you give a value that won't fit in the number of digits, it caps the value and uses the greatest value that can fit.

In this case, the 10-digit value of 999.9999999, rounded up to 1000.0000000.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html says:

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.

In other words, *you* gave it the constraint to max out at 1000.0000000, because you told it to max out at 10 digits, of which 7 digits are to the right of the decimal point.

```
mysql> create table f ( f float(10,7));

mysql> insert into f values (1196.104);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'f' at row 1 |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+

mysql> select * from f;
+--------------+
| f            |
+--------------+
| 1000.0000000 |
+--------------+
```

If you want to store larger values, declare `FLOAT` with enough digits to hold the values you use. For example, the value 1196.104 could be inserted to `FLOAT(11,7)` or `FLOAT(10,6)`.

Or you could use `FLOAT` with no arguments, and it will not constrain the number of digits at all.

There are some caveats about FLOAT. It's an inexact numeric type, and it will have rounding errors. This is unavoidable because of the way FLOAT is implemented, and it affects every programming language.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Also see my old tweet about this:
https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/347561901460447232

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Really helpful, I updated the field to float(15, 7) now when I insert 1196.104 in the field it stores as 1196.1040039 how did it get the last 0039 part after 1196.104?

Comment: It's the rounding error also in the first link Bill posted.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make them drink.